# /wp-admin/ & /wp-login.php redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, ssl, redirect, wp-admin

I installed a plugin called Hide My WP to change the site structure, but given that I was using a custom theme, it broke some of the features. So I manually deleted the plugin from the plugins folder, but since then I haven't been able to access /wp-admin/, which redirects to a 404 error.

I've tried every fix I read, from changing file permissions according to "Hardening Wordpress", resetting .htaccess, reuploading the /wp-admin/ folder & wp-login.php, defining SSL only on wp-config.php as well as the wp_options table on the database, but the error persists. I still can't login.

wp-login.php has a redirect loop, which might be caused by a forced SSL feature that the plugin originally enabled. Is there any way to reset this, without having to create it all over again?

Comment: You might have better luck at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ since this is not a specific programming issue.

Comment: You need deactivate this plugin in database

Comment: If you rename the folder for the plugin on the hosting, WP won't be able to find it and won't load it - this should let you log in to the admin. Then rename the folder back to its proper name, and deactivate it from the plugins page.

Answer (score -1):

You must disable redirects to the site's path

Comment: Just dropping in an unrelated link at the end of your answer makes it appear that this post is intended as spam. That your account is suspended for promotional content makes that more likely.